# Adjusting height of the panels in jquery Accordion widget

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using jquery accordion widget. I want the height of the panles in the widget to get adjusted according to their contents. For that I tried using "setter" method of options we have and also while instantiating  I tried setting the value of 'heightStyle'. It even works for one of the accordion widget instance but for the other one I have added, it simply doesn't work.

Is there any other way to adjust the height rather than overriding the accordion css?
In My case, for the accordion inside '**fullpageaccordion**' div, **its taking the same height for all the elements per the first element in the accordion though I have given the heightStyle as content while instantiating**.
Please find my code below:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/jquery-ui.css"/>-->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #container{
            width: 99%;
            border: 1px solid #ff00ff;
            padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
            min-height: 750px;
        }

        #accordiondiv{
            position: relative;
            width: 30%;
            border: 1px solid #dddddd;
            float: left;
        }
        .collapsibledivs{
            position: relative;
            width:69%;
            border: 1px solid green;
            min-height: 70px;
            float: left;
            padding-right: 0.7%;
        }
        .collapsibleheaders{
            background: #efefef;
            width: 100%;
            float:left;
            padding-left: 10px;
        }
        #fullpageaccordion{
            width: 69%;
            border: 1px solid blue;
            float:left;
        }
        #fullpageaccordion .accordion h2{
            color: rgb(145,186,222);
            background:rgb(242,242,242);
        }

        .deletebtn{
            float: right;
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;
            cursor: pointer;
            background-image: url(./images/minus.png);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: 100%;
            background-position: center;
        }
        .unorderedlist{
            list-style-type: none;
        }
        .breadcrumdiv{
            background: #ffffff;
            width: 49%;
            min-height: 40px;
            float:left;
            border: 1px solid pink;
        }
        .fontformat{
            background: #dddddd;
            width: 45%;
            min-height: 40px;
            float:left;
            border: 1px solid pink;
        }
        .breadcrumwrapper{
            position: relative;
            width:69%;
            border: 1px solid green;
            min-height: 0px;
            float: left;
            padding-right: 0.7%;
        }
        .backbtn{
            height: 40px;
            width: 40px;
            background: url(./images/tool_arrow_right.png);
            float: left;
            cursor: pointer;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: 60%;
            background-position: 65% 60%;
            border-right: 1px solid #dddddd;
        }
        .nextbtn{
            height: 40px;
            width: 40px;
            background: url(./images/tool_arrow_left.png);
            float: left;
            cursor: pointer;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: 60%;
            background-position: 40% 60%;
            border-right: 1px solid #dddddd;
        }
        .ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content{
            /*height: 100px !important;
            overflow-y:scroll !important;*/
        }

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $( "#fullpageaccordion .accordion" ).accordion({autoHeight: false});
            $(".breadcrumwrapper button[name=back]").addClass("backbtn");
            $(".accordion").accordion({
                heightStyle: "content"
            });
            $("#fullpageaccordion .accordion").accordion({
                heightStyle: "content"
            });
            $(".subaccordion").accordion({
                heightStyle: "content"
            });
            $(".deletebtn").click(function(){
                console.log('on delete click');
                if($("#collapsibeldivs").css("display") == "block"){
                    $(this).parents(".collapsibledivs").animate({height:"0px"});
                }
                else{
                    $($(this).parents(".collapsibledivs")).toggle('show');
                }
            });
            $(".breadcrumwrapper [name=back]").click(function(){
                var classApplied = $(this).attr('class');
                console.log('class applied:'+classApplied);
                if(classApplied == "backbtn"){
                    console.log('back btn clicked....');
                    $(".breadcrumdiv").animate({width:"95%"});
                    $(".fontformat").animate({width:"0%"});
                    $($(".breadcrumwrapper button[name=back]")[0]).removeClass("backbtn");
                    $($(".breadcrumwrapper button[name=back]")[0]).addClass("nextbtn");
                }
                else{
                    $(".breadcrumdiv").animate({width:"49%"});
                    $(".fontformat").animate({width:"45%"});
                    $($(".breadcrumwrapper button[name=back]")[0]).removeClass("nextbtn");
                    $($(".breadcrumwrapper button[name=back]")[0]).addClass("backbtn");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="accordiondiv">
            <div class="accordion">
                <h3>My Pages</h3>
                <div>
                    <div class="subaccordion">
                        <h4>Page 1</h4>
                        <div>   
                            <ul class="unorderedlist">
                                <li> page 1.1 </li>
                                <li> page 1.2 </li>
                                <li> page 1.3 </li>
                                <li> page 1.4 </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <h4>Page 2</h4>
                        <div>   
                            <ul class="unorderedlist">
                                <li> page 2.1 </li>
                                <li> page 2.2 </li>
                                <li> page 2.3 </li>
                                <li> page 2.4 </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <h4>Page 3</h4>
                        <div>   
                            <ul class="unorderedlist">
                                <li> page 3.1 </li>
                                <li> page 3.2 </li>
                                <li> page 3.3 </li>
                                <li> page 3.4 </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h3>My Drafts</h3>
                <div>
                    <ul class="unorderedlist">
                        <li> page 1 </li>
                        <li> page 2 </li>
                        <li> page 3 </li>
                        <li> page 4 </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <h3>My Public Pages</h3>
                <div>
                    <ul class="unorderedlist">
                        <li> page 1 </li>
                        <li> page 2 </li>
                        <li> page 3 </li>
                        <li> page 4 </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="breadcrumwrapper">
            <div class="breadcrumdiv">

            </div>
            <div class="fontformat">

            </div>
            <button name="back"/>
        </div>
        <div class="collapsibledivs">
            <div class="collapsibleheaders">
                LANE 1
                <button class="deletebtn"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="fullpageaccordion">
            <div class="accordion">
                <h2>LORIUM IMPSUM HEADING</h2>
                <div>
                    <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
                        <li>
                            <label style="width:20%;">Item1:</label>
                            <input type="text" style="width:25%;margin-left:4%;">
                            <input type="text" style="width:25%;margin-left:4%;">
                            <input type="text" style="width:25%;margin-left:4%;">
                        </li>
                        <li><div style="min-height:20px;background:transperant;"></div></li>
                        <li>
                            <label style="width:20%;">Item2:</label>
                            <input type="text" style="width:25%;;margin-left:4%;">
                            <input type="text" style="width:25%;;margin-left:4%;">
                            <input type="text" style="width:25%;;margin-left:4%;">
                        </li>
                        <li><div style="min-height:20px;background:transperant;"></div></li>
                        <li>
                            <label style="width:20%;">Item3:</label>
                            <input type="text" style="width:25%;;margin-left:4%;">
                            <input type="text" style="width:25%;;margin-left:4%;">
                            <input type="text" style="width:25%;;margin-left:4%;">
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <h2>SIDEBAR</h2>
                <div>

                </div>
                <h2>LANE 1</h2>
                <div>

                </div>
                <h2>LANE 2</h2>
                <div>

                </div>
                <h2>LANE 3</h2>
                <div>

                </div>
                <h2>FOOTER</h2>
                <div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is you are using the instantiation syntax on the full page accordion twice. You have:

```
$( "#fullpageaccordion .accordion" ).accordion({autoHeight: false});
```

and

```
$("#fullpageaccordion .accordion").accordion({
    heightStyle: "content"
 });
```

The second one is being discarded, I believe. To change an option after instantion, you'd use:

```
$("#fullpageaccordion .accordion").accordion("option", "heightStyle", "content" );
```

Or, you could set both properties together in the first call:

```
$( "#fullpageaccordion .accordion" ).accordion({
   autoHeight: false,
   heightStyle: "content"
});
```

Also, is autoHeight even a valid option in the current version of jqueryUI? You might just want to delete the first call.